# How could a for loop be related to a stack overflow?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I've met a piece of code that will cause a stack overflow exception only when a for loop repeats over a certain number of times.

Here's the code:

```
public class Stackoverflow
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>() {1, 2};

        Container container = new Container {List = list};
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)     // This matters
        {
            foreach (var item in container.List)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Container
{
    private IEnumerable<int> list;

    public IEnumerable<int> List
    {
        get
        {
            //return list.OrderBy(x => x);  <- This is OK
            list = list.OrderBy(x => x);    // This is not
            return list;
        }
        set { list = value; }
    }

}
```

When the method Test() is executed, [you can see a long series of "1" and "2" being printed on screen before the error actually happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6bw3.png) (which I think means the for loop is advancing properly)

And the stack overflow exception does not occur if the condition becomes "i < 1000" (or less).

[The memory dump showed "List.Orderby" is likely the direct cause of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZIO.png)

I know it's bad practice to write a "get" like this, but I don't understand what is causing the stack overflow exception here, and why it seems to be accumulative rather than a recursive death trap.

This is probably a trap in the enumeration code, or something by the compiler, or just my oversight?
Anyway, looking for an explanation, thanks for your help.

[Stacktrace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DC5k.png)

In Text:

```
000000e86215e460 00007ffe28670f7c (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567738 +0x2c System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetEnumerator())
000000e86215e4a0 00007ffe849ce396 (MethodDesc 00007ffe844a4ce8 +0x66 System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>))
000000e86215e4c0 00007ffe86bad279 (MethodDesc 00007ffe866d7630 +0x19 System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleRelease(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle))
000000e86215e510 00007ffe28670fe7 (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567e80 +0x47 System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1+<GetEnumerator>d__1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext())
000000e86215e520 00007ffe28670f7c (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567738 +0x2c System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetEnumerator())
000000e86215e560 00007ffe849ce396 (MethodDesc 00007ffe844a4ce8 +0x66 System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>))
000000e86215e580 00007ffe86c5b552 (MethodDesc 00007ffe867e3f60 +0xf2 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr))
000000e86215e5d0 00007ffe28670fe7 (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567e80 +0x47 System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1+<GetEnumerator>d__1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext())
000000e86215e5e0 00007ffe28670f7c (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567738 +0x2c System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetEnumerator())
000000e86215e5e8 00007ffe86c5b526 (MethodDesc 00007ffe867e3f60 +0xc6 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr))
000000e86215e620 00007ffe849ce396 (MethodDesc 00007ffe844a4ce8 +0x66 System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>))
000000e86215e690 00007ffe28670fe7 (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567e80 +0x47 System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1+<GetEnumerator>d__1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext())
000000e86215e6a0 00007ffe28670f7c (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567738 +0x2c System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetEnumerator())
000000e86215e6e0 00007ffe849ce396 (MethodDesc 00007ffe844a4ce8 +0x66 System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>))
000000e86215e710 00007ffe86b9b46a (MethodDesc 00007ffe86950f90 +0x8a System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean, Boolean))
000000e86215e750 00007ffe28670fe7 (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567e80 +0x47 System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1+<GetEnumerator>d__1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext())
000000e86215e760 00007ffe28670f7c (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567738 +0x2c System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetEnumerator())
000000e86215e7a0 00007ffe849ce396 (MethodDesc 00007ffe844a4ce8 +0x66 System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>))
000000e86215e7d0 00007ffe28670da5 (MethodDesc 00007ffe28565c68 +0xe5 ConsoleTest.Container.get_List())
000000e86215e810 00007ffe28670fe7 (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567e80 +0x47 System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1+<GetEnumerator>d__1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext())
000000e86215e820 00007ffe28670f7c (MethodDesc 00007ffe28567738 +0x2c System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetEnumerator())
000000e86215e860 00007ffe2867065f (MethodDesc 00007ffe28565b98 +0x11f ConsoleTest.Stackoverflow.Test())
000000e86215e900 00007ffe286704ba (MethodDesc 00007ffe28565ac0 +0x3a ConsoleTest.Program.Main(System.String[]))
```

Comment: We need the stacktrace.

Comment: `list = list.OrderBy(x => x)` builds an ever larger expression tree. After a few iterations of this you have `<originalList>.OrderBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x)...` This is radically different from `return list.OrderBy(x => x)`.

Comment: @tkausl I've uploaded the stacktrace.

Comment: @ck1521 please post stacktrace as text

Comment: Is list null?  That would account for the error.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert ah! Thanks, this does make some sense but what made the code expand itself during run-time? from IL I can only find a "new list" and a pointer exchange operation, is the expansion inferred somewhere in the IL?

Comment: There is no explicit expansion in the code and there needn't be. You invoke `Enumerable.OrderBy(this IEnumerable<...>`), which returns a *new* `IEnumerable` that you then assign. Rinse and repeat. Eventually the stack overflows when we actually try to enumerate this enormously nested chain of calls as an iterator in the `foreach` (the `OrderBy` delegates effectively form an enormous call chain that is not subject to something like tail call optimization).

Comment: @barbsan Stacktrace in text updated... a part of it though, the rest of the stack basically repeats itself

Comment: When you iterate the last result of `OrderBy`, it will need to call the previous level of `OrderBy` to get the things to order, which will need to call the previous level, which will call the previous level, which will call the previous level, etc. You tack on one additional level each time you read the property.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert ok...this explained the issue although I still don't get it that why the code need to be expanded dynamically in each iteration of the loop, sounds like .net is doing some eval() to me. Is there any specific mechanism or keyword I can google that is related to this type of behavior?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but it seems to be predicated on a misconception of how LINQ actually works. LINQ queries use deferred execution; this is well-known and easily searched for. The `.OrderBy()` acts as a transformation/builder; nothing actually happens until the query as a whole is enumerated (this is crucial to the way LINQ allows you to build queries for external providers like databases). There is no `eval()` going on in the sense that no text is being parsed as code, here -- rather the LINQ methods act as builders.

Comment: @lasse-vågsæther-karlsen OK... does it mean the "List.OrderBy" is actually not executed in each iteration of the loop? I mean if it did, I would assume each iteration ended up with a sorted list rather than an ever-expanding call chain, is that so? And... I'm sorry but I still don't get the "why" part

Comment: Read Peters answer below, it should tell you what is happening. `IEnumerable<T>` is a lazily evaluated thing, and if you store a LINQ expression into such a variable, you're waiting to execute the expression until you iterate over it, since you're stacking lazily evaluated expressions on top of lazily evaluated expressions, eventually the stack topples over.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert finally I get it, thanks for your explanation, it's my understanding about LINQ, I know it's not syntactic sugar but never the why, until now. :)

Comment: Short of it: This: `IEnumerable<int> x = someList.OrderBy(i => i);` does not in fact order the list. This code is actually super-cheap, regardless of how big the list is. **However**, what you have stored is a "recipe" for how to obtain the values, used when you later iterate over this `x` variable, and when you do, first we'll order the list, then we'll return the ordered values. If you order `x` even, you now have 2 steps that orders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your **`get`** property replaces the `list` variable each time with a new object defined by `list.OrderBy(x => x);`.

Note that `OrderBy(x => x)` does not do any ordering yet, it creates an object that defines how to return items, which only gets executed if/when you iterate it with e.g. `foreach`.

I will try to show the consequences of this:

- Before the first run, `list` equals **`List<int>() {1, 2}`**
- After it ran once, `list` equals **`(List<int>() {1, 2}).OrderBy(x => x)`**
- After it ran twice, `list` equals **`(List<int>() {1, 2}).OrderBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x)`**
- After it ran 10000 times... I wont even attempt to show what `list` contains.

Enumerating that 10000-fold-nested object is causing 10000 Enumerator objects to be spun up, each performing an ordered retrieval of the previous one, until the original source `List<int>`is encountered. Apparently it runs out of space before the source list is reached.

The fix is to not re-assign list every time, or (if you feel you must for some reason) then make it "do" the OrderBy by using ToList():

```
get
{
    list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); // creates a new list and does not keep to OrderBy() object
    return list;
}
```

That would still cause redundant re-ordering and re-assignment every time the property is accessed. If you need the ordering always, it will be far more efficient to put that logic in the setter, so it will happen just once:

```
get { return list; }
set { list = value.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); }
```

Comment: Arguably, the better solution would be to change the `set` to incorporate the `OrderBy` and keep the `get` as a simple return of the value. This does not require materializing the list until necessary, but without the nested catastrophe (as well as changing a value in a getter, which is just bad period). The original approach of directly returning `list.OrderBy(...)` is also fine, of course.

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand it now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yep! That logic belongs in the setter.